# ReactiveSwift Simple Example

Tags: swift3, reactive-cocoa

I've read the [documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift), gone through their wonderful Playground example, searched S.O., and reached the extent of my [google-fu](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=google-fu), but I cannot for the life of me wrap my head around how to use ReactiveSwift.

Given the following....

```
class SomeModel {
    var mapType: MKMapType = .standard
    var selectedAnnotation: MKAnnotation?
    var annotations = [MKAnnotation]()
    var enableRouteButton = false

    // The rest of the implementation...
}

class SomeViewController: UIViewController {

    let model: SomeModel
    let mapView = MKMapView(frame: .zero) // It's position is set elsewhere
    @IBOutlet var routeButton: UIBarButtonItem?

    init(model: SomeModel) {
        self.model = model
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }


    // The rest of the implementation...
}
```

....how can I use ReactiveSwift to initialize `SomeViewController` with the values from `SomeModel`, then update `SomeViewController` whenever the values in `SomeModel` change?

I've never used reactive anything before, but everything I read leads me to believe this should be possible. *It is making me crazy.*

I realize there is much more to ReactiveSwift than what I'm trying to achieve in this example, but if someone could please use it to help me get started, I would greatly appreciate it. I'm hoping once I get this part, the rest will just "click".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First you'll want to use `MutableProperty` instead of plain types in your Model. This way, you can observe changes to them.

```
class Model {
    let mapType = MutableProperty<MKMapType>(.standard)
    let selectedAnnotation = MutableProperty<MKAnnotation?>(nil)
    let annotations = MutableProperty<[MKAnnotation]>([])
    let enableRouteButton = MutableProperty<Bool>(false)
}
```

In your ViewController, you can then bind those and observe those however necessary:

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {

    let viewModel: Model
    let mapView = MKMapView(frame: .zero) // It's position is set elsewhere
    @IBOutlet var routeButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    init(viewModel: Model) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        routeButton.reactive.isEnabled <~ viewModel.enableRouteButton
        viewModel.mapType.producer.startWithValues { [weak self] mapType in
            // Process new map type
        }
        // Rest of bindings
    }
    // The rest of the implementation...
}
```

Note that `MutableProperty` has both, a `.signal` as well as a `.signalProducer`. 
If you immediately need the current value of a `MutableProperty` (e.g. for initial setup), use `.signalProducer` which immediately sends an event with the current value as well as any changes.

If you only need to react to future changes, use `.signal` which will only send events for future changes.

[Reactive Cocoa 5.0 will add UIKit bindings](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/releases/tag/5.0.0-alpha.1) which you can use to directly bind UI elements to your reactive layer like done with `routeButton` in the example.

Comment: That "click" you just heard was everything making sense after I read your answer. Thank you for breaking it down in the example, as it made all the difference!

Comment: Glad I could help