# ReactiveSwift - Updating Value Of MutableProperty?

Tags: swift3, reactive-cocoa

As a followup to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40836748/862224) question, which received [this fantastic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40840433/862224), and using the following example...

```
class Model {
    let mapType = MutableProperty<MKMapType>(.standard)
}

class SomeViewController: UIViewController {

    let viewModel: Model
    var mapView: MKMapView!

    init(viewModel: Model) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapView = // Create the map view
        viewModel.mapType.producer.startWithValues { [weak self] mapType in
            self?.mapView.mapType = mapType
        }
        // Rest of bindings
    }
    // The rest of the implementation...
}

class SomeOtherViewController: UIViewController {

    let viewModel: Model
    var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

    init(viewModel: Model) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        // Pretend we've setup the segmentedControl, and set its action to `updateMap(sender:)`...
        // The rest of the initialization...
    }

    func updateMap(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        let newMapType =...
        self.viewModel.mapType = newMapType // How do I update this value?
    }
    // The rest of the implementation...
}
```

How can I update the value of `Model.mapType`, and have its changes sent to any observers (like `SomeViewController` in the example)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to set its `value` property, this will trigger changes to be sent to observers automatically.

`self.viewModel.mapType.value = newMapType`

Comment: Wow...I could have sworn I tried exactly that. *facepalm* I appreciate the quick answer!

Comment: Also could've sworn I marked this is the excepted answer.....  Fixed, and thank you again!